# Передача массива в рекурсивную функцию

Tags: c++

У меня есть рекурсивная функция,которая вызывает саму себя 5 раз   int rec( int **array). Как сделать так,что бы передаваемый массив не менялся в предыдущем вызове рекурсии.

Вот код.Ф-я rec вызывыет саму себя раза 3-4.нужно 4то бы в этих 3-4 вызовах массив field Не менялся. Т.е если изменили в 1ом вызове,то во втором вызове он уже оставался таким каким был .

```js
int rec(int ** field, int ** key, int ** primaty_field) {
  cout << "RE1C #" << r++ << endl;
  int size = 5;

  if (r > 0) {
    print(primaty_field, size);
    print(field, size);
  }


  int count;
  int value = 0;
  int fuul = 0;
  int grow[2] = {
    1,
    1
  }; //Массив отве4ающий за рост каждого клю4а


  //Условие выхода из рекурсии
  for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++)
    for (int jj = 0; jj < size; jj++) {
      if (primaty_field[ii][jj] != '*')
        fuul++;

    }


  if (r == 10) //если весь field заполнен
  {

    print(field, size);
    return 0; ///ВЫХОД ИЗ РЕКУРСИИ
  }

 
  while (growth_sequence(grow) == true) {
    //cout << "Grow : " << grow[0] << "   " << grow[1] << endl;
    count = -1;
    value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //////////
    { //////////   Ищем нужный клю4 на поле
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) ///////
      {
        if (key[i][j] != '*') //Если нашли Клю4 
        {
          count++;
          if (grow[count] == 1) //Вверх
          {
            if (Check_top_empty(primaty_field, i, j, key[i][j], size) == true) {
              top(primaty_field, i, j, key[i][j], size);
              value++;
            } else {
              recovery_field(field, primaty_field, size);
            } //рекурсия,т.к нам не подходит текущаяя комбинация grow
          }
          if (grow[count] == 2) //Вниз
          {
            if (Check_bottom_empty(primaty_field, i, j, key[i][j], size) == true) {
              bottom(primaty_field, i, j, key[i][j], size);
              value++;
            } else {
              recovery_field(field, primaty_field, size);
            }
          }

          if (grow[count] == 3) //Вправо
          {
            if (Check_right_empty(primaty_field, i, j, key[i][j], size) == true) {
              right(primaty_field, i, j, key[i][j], size);
              value++;
            } else {
              recovery_field(field, primaty_field, size);
            }
          }

          if (grow[count] == 4) //Влево
          {
            if (Check_left_empty(primaty_field, i, j, key[i][j], size) == true) {
              left(primaty_field, i, j, key[i][j], size);
              value++;
            } else {
              recovery_field(field, primaty_field, size);
            }
          }



        }
      }
    }
    if (value == 2) //Возможная комбинация
    {
      if (r == 10) {
        cout << grow[0] << "  " << grow[1] << endl;
      }


      int n = -1;
      cout << grow[0] << "  " << grow[1] << endl;
      rec(primaty_field, key, primaty_field); ///Рекурсия

      /// print(primaty_field, size);////На этом месте должна быть рекурсия
      recovery_field(primaty_field, field, size);
      //cout << grow[0] << "  " << grow[1] << endl;
      //print(primaty_field, size);
    }

  }

  growth_sequence(grow); //меняем Grow для следующего обхода.

}
```

Comment: кхм, кхм, не писать код, который его меняет

Comment: Ну так: не менять его - он и не будет меняться. А если все таки нужно менять, то сохранить его получится только ручным копированием.

Comment: "если изменили в 1ом вызове,то во втором вызове он уже оставался таким каким был" - по волшебству, что ли?

Comment: ужасная функция...

Answer (score 0):

Так как мне не понятно что вы хотели делать и для чего столько условных операций, отвечу только на вопрос: как не изменять массив более одного раза (если я вас правильно понял).

В самой функции, где у вас меняются данные массива, обьявляйте статический булевский обьект(или типа int) и после любого  изменения  в массиве, меняйте и его значение и по этому значению определите менять данные или нет. Например:

```
void some_function(Some_type* m, ...) {
    static bool b = false;
    if(!b) {
       // действия, изменяющие массив
        b = true;
       // после этого, при следующем вызове функции
       // условие не выполнится и никакого действия не произойдет
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто создаете копию вашего массива. Проводите изменения над исходным массивом и передаете ранее созданную копию на следующую ступень рекурсии, либо проводите изменения над ранее созданной копией и передаете исходный массив на следующую ступень рекурсии.